# How can I launch a slave agent via SSH on Jenkins programmatically?

Tags: ssh, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

How can I launch a slave agent via SSH on Jenkins programmatically?

Or enable auto refresh such that Jenkins checks automatically to see if a slave is online.

Basically I have a job which reboots one of the slaves. I need some jobs to run on the same slave after it boots up (by chaining another job using the *Startup Trigger* plugin) without any manual intervention in between these steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins will automatically reconnect to the slave after it's rebooted; the master checks the slave connection every minute or so (I'm not sure of the exact interval without digging into the source code).

As long as the slave configuration is still defined in the Jenkins master, you shouldn't need to do anything on the slave machine.

Comment: You may want to change 'should' to 'should not' in the last sentence otherwise it looks like the OP will need to do something. I tried to edit the post but you have to add / change at least 6 characters for the edit to be allowed.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out , impatience was the villian

Comment: What does "every few minutes" mean, or where is this setting in Jenkins?

Comment: @Colleen clarified the answer a bit - as far as I know the retry interval isn't configurable.

Comment: btw, from looking at my logs, in our setup the interval seems to be 23 minutes. Weird interval, but w/e.